# Wordpress: Change Image based on custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, metadata, custom-fields

I have custom fields set up in Wordpress and I'd like to change an image based on the value in that field.

Something like:

- If custom_field_value = 1, show image A.
- If custom_field_value 2, show image B.

I'm trying to create a review score system that changes an image based on the score. Like if the score is a 10, an image will be displayed. If the score is a 5, a different image will be displayed.

I hope this makes sense, I would try to write something more in depth, but I havent been able to find much on this to logically create a solution. Everything I keep finding uses an `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_score', true)` but I'm not trying to echo the value (which would be the numerical score), I'm trying to change an image based on the "review_score".

Again, I hope this makes some sense, I would love some help. Thanks so much all.

Answer (score 0):

So... don't echo the value.

```
$review_score = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_score', true);
if(!empty($review_score)) {
  switch ($review_score) :
    case 0 :
      // one image
    break;
    case 5 :
      // another image
    break;
    case 10 :
      // yet another image
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you possibly go a bit further with the implementation. Sorry, I'm still pretty amateur. I've got this so far: 
http://notepad.cc/reviewscore 
http://jsfiddle.net/AaysE/1/


Sorry for any inconvenience.